# Сложности с пониманием темы "Множества" в Turbo Pascal.

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!
Снова обращаюсь к знатокам :)

Вопрос от новичка, который только-только начал
изучать Turbo Pascal и постепенно добрался
до темы «Множества».

Тема в общем смысле кажется понятной, но, в то же
время кажется, что… ничего совсем не понятно.
Если честно, в голове уже каша от изученного материала…
Но очень хочется понять эту тему, прежде, чем идти
в изучении дальше.

Ниже я привожу вопросы, на которые прошу Вас ответить.

Вопросов много. Я понимаю, что ответы на них могут
быть утомительными… Но если уж не на все, то хоть
 на некоторые из них, ответьте, пожалуйста.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

**1.** В памяти отводится по 1 биту под каждый элемент,
находящийся во множестве.

**2.** Перечислимый тип данных сам по себе является
множеством.

**3.** Не совсем понятно объявление множеств в программе.

а)

```
type SetByte = set of byte;
var sb : SetByte;
```

Правильно ли я понимаю в данном случае, что:

а1) Множество задается в разделе type, потому что
по сути, создается необходимый пользовательский тип?

а2) В разделе var нужно объявить специальную переменную,
которая будет являться «представителем» того пользовательского
типа, который был создан в разделе type. Т.е. переменной
созданного множества.

а3) В программе можно будет выполнять все
обычные операции, предусмотренные ЯП, над
переменной, которая является «представителем»
множества.

a4) В данном случае sb ялвяется одним из элементов
множества SetByte. И таких элементов (переменных)
можно создать столько, сколько может вместить в
себя множество.

б)

```
type SetChisla = set of 10..20;
var Index : SetChisla=[12,15,17];
```

б1) Понятно, что задается множество в диапазоне от
10 до 20. Но почему здесь не указывается какого
типа это множество? Или итак понятно, что это
целочисленный тип?

б2) Если уже определено, что множество задано
в диапазоне от 10 до 20, что значат цифры в
квадратных скобках? Здесь прописывается то,
что в заданном множестве будут присутствовать
именно эти три элемента: 12, 15 и 17? Т.е. происходит
обычная операция присваивания?

б3) Почему в качестве идентификатора переменной
множественного типа участвует ключевое слово index?
Может быть это опечатка автора учебного пособия?

в)

```
type Symbol = set of char;
var Letter, Digits, Sign : Symbol;
```

в1) Почему можно создавать несколько переменных,
являющихся представителями одного и того же
множества? Как они взаимодействуют друг с другом?

г)

```
type Month = (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August,
            September, October, November, December);
   Season : set of Month;
var Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn, Vacation, WarmSeason : Season;
```

г1) Здесь создано множество Season на основе перечислимого
типа?

г2) Какими тогда будут элементы этого множества?
January, February… December ? Или Winter…WarmSeason?
Или множество будет содержать
и отдельно заданные элементы и элементы, входящие
в перечислимый тип Month?

г3) Почему в строчке Season : set of Month;
стоит двоеточие, а не знак равно? Или это просто
опечатка в пособии?

д) `var Operation : set of (Plus, Minus, Mult, Divid);`

д1) Почему в данном случае происходит объявление
множества в разделе переменных? И почему опять
через : , а не через знак = ?

д2) После set of должен быть прописан тип данных,
которому принадлежат элементы множества. Тогда
в этом случае мне не понятно, какому типу принадлежат
элементы заданного множества?

е) `var Param : set of 0..9=[0, 2, 4, 6, 8];`

е1) Здесь задано множество целого типа?

е2) Во множество записали элементы 
0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ?

**4.** В пособии написано, что множества часто используются
как константы. Тогда, определив множество в разделе
const, нужно ли его прописывать в разделе type?

Прошу, пожалуйста, объясните доступным, понятным языком :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`set` — это тип. Можно создавать много переменных такого типа.**

3а1 Не *множество* задается в разделе `typе`, а ***тип*** "*множество чисел типа* `byte`".

3a3 Переменные не являются представителями множества, а сами являются множествами, то есть содержат в себе элементы заданного типа.

3б2

```
type SetChisla = set of 10..20;
```

означает, что в переменную типа `SetChisla` можно "положить" только числа от 10 до 20.

```
var Index : SetChisla=[12,15,17];
```

множество `Index` типа `SetChisla`, в которое сразу положили числа 12, 15 и 17

3б3 index — это не ключевое слово

3д Тоже самое, `Operation` — это переменная типа "множество элементов перечислимого типа `(Plus, Minus, Mult, Divid)`".

3е Тоже самое, `Param` — переменная типа "множество целых чисел от нуля до девяти", и ей сразу задается значение `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`.

4 Пример:

```
type SetDigit = set of 0..9; (* тип - множество цифр *)
(* две константы этого типа - нечетные и четные цифры *)
const odd_digits : SetDigit = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
      even_digits : SetDigit = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
      odd_digits2 : set of 0..9 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]; {тоже самое, что и odd_digits}
```

---

*PS Все разделы (`const`, `var`, `type`) можно чередовать:*

```
const minn = 10;
      maxn = 1000;
type vector = array[1..max] of integer;
var n, m : integer;

const inf = 2147483647;

var a : vector;
```

Comment: @Андрей, благодарю за ответы! Очень понятно все "разжевано". Вот бы в учебниках так же понятно писали :) Сейчас именно они мои учителя, потому что я взялась за изучение Pascal самостоятельно :)

Answer (score 4):

1. да, скорее всего по одному биту, но это Вас тревожить не должно. Это личное дело компилятора, как он там все сделает.
2. нет. Но с помощью перечислямого типа можно указать допустимые элементы для множества.
   3

а1) да, можно в разделе type. Но можно и разделе var (в виде `a:set of 1..10;`

а2) а если не объявить, то что будете делать с типом?

а3) да.

а4) нет. sb - это переменная, которая содержит множество, а не один элемент этого множества.

б1) а здесь тип не принципиален. Главное, что бы он был перечисляем для компилятора.

б2) `var Index : SetChisla=[12,15,17];` здесь производится инициализация переменной-множества, и будет три элемента.

б3) ну так решил автор. Насколько я помню, в турбопаскале это не было ключевым словом. А может просто не подумал.

в1) а почему нельзя? можно. При этом только внутренние ограничения компилятора могут быть преградой. Как взаимодействуют? как попросите, так и будут. Можно сравнивать на равенство, на то, что одно множество является подмножеством другого, складывать множества.

г1) да.

г2) Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn, Vacation, WarmSeason - это переменные множества, которые могут содержать месяца.

г3) опечатка.

д1) если нужна переменная-множество какого то типа только одна, то можно не объявлять пользовательский тип, а сразу, по месту объявить. Синтаксис правильный.

д2) безименного типа. Просто есть некий тип множества без имени, указанные допустимые элементы.

е1) не совсем. относитесь к ним как к элементам, а не числам.

е2) да.

4) можно по разному определить множество

```
const test:set of 0..9 = [0,2];
```

и не нужно ничего писать в раздел type:)

Comment: @Андрей, в разделе type?)

Comment: там нет var. Либо var в второй строке, но тогда что делать с третьей, либо там все таки равно, тогда все так как нужно. Но там нет `Operation`:)

Comment: @Sh4dow в вопросе написано так : "д) `var Operation : set of (Plus, Minus, Mult, Divid);`"

Comment: @KoVadim, огромное спасибо! За все ответы и за время, которое Вы уделили моим вопросам. Ваши ответы и ответы @Андрей я даже законспектировала :) Мою просьбу Вы выполнили - объяснили предельно просто и ясно :)